# Server-Sent Events in Flask work locally but not on production (linode)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server

I'm trying to get a progress bar to work in Flask. I use a [Server Sent Events](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html) for that. When I run it in local development server, then everything works well and I can see in the browser real time added numbers in /progress window and progress bar works no problems.

But if I run it in Linux server (Linode), then browser windows hangs for 10 sec and after that progress bar jumps to 100. I am beginner and do not understand why it works in local machine and why not in the remote server. Please somebody explain. And also - which would be a practical solution to this.

Flask - app.py

```
@app.route('/progress')
def progress():
    def progress_func():
        x = 0
        while x < 100:
            time.sleep(1)
            x = x + 10
            yield 'data:' + str(x) + "\n\n"
    return Response(progress_func(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

js

```
var source = new EventSource("/progress");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
    };
```

index.html

```
<div>
    <div class="progress" style="width: 100%; height: 6px;">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 6px" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience that problem can be caused by the reverse proxy between flask and the frontend.

If you use nginx you need to set `proxy_buffering` to `off` in order to be able to use SSE

EDIT:

While looking at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering I noticed that you can achieve the same result by setting the `X-Accel-Buffering` header to `no` in the flask response. This solution is better since it's limited to this specific response.

Comment: Adding `proxy_buffering off;` to the `http` section in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and running `sudo systemctl restart nginx` worked for my Flask app running in a DigitalOcean Droplet.